# MediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null) will cause RuntimeException when it work in a thread, why?

Tags: android

I invoke mRecordHelper.StartRecord(mRecordArg,myResultCode,mydata) in a thread, it display the following error, I think `MediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null)` cause the error.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.registerCallback(MediaProjection.java:80)
```

**Call code**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen Cast Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        final MPublicPar.RecordArg mRecordArg =new MPublicPar().new RecordArg(mContext);
        final int myResultCode=resultCode;
        final Intent mydata=data;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mRecordHelper.StartRecord(mRecordArg,myResultCode,mydata);
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

**RecordHelper.cs**

```
public class RecordHelper {

    private  MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private  MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private  VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private  MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;

    private Context mContext;
    private Toast mToastText;

    public RecordHelper(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    public void StartRecord(RecordArg mRecordArg, int resultCode, Intent data){

        initRecorder(mRecordArg);
        prepareRecorder();

        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();

         //This will cause error
        //mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);

        mVirtualDisplay=createVirtualDisplay(mRecordArg);

        DelayStartRecord(mRecordArg);
    }


    public void StopRecord(){
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();

            mVirtualDisplay.release();
            mMediaRecorder.release();

            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;

        }catch (Exception e){
            Utility.LogError("StopRecord Error " + e.getMessage() + "  " + e.toString());
        }
    }


    private void DelayStartRecord(RecordArg mRecordArg){
        mMediaRecorder.start();       
    }



    private void initRecorder(RecordArg mRecordArg) {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mRecordArg.screenWidth, mRecordArg.screenHeight);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mRecordArg.videoFilename);
    }


    private void prepareRecorder() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utility.LogError(e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utility.LogError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay(RecordArg mRecordArg) {
          return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("ScreenRecord",
                 mRecordArg.screenWidth, mRecordArg.screenHeight, mRecordArg.mScreenDensity,
                 DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                 mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null /*Handler*/);
    }



    //Called when the MediaProjection session is no longer valid.
    private  class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- Call `registerCallback()` on the main application thread, or
- Supply a `Handler` as the second parameter to `registerCallback()`, or (probably)
- Call `registerCallback()` from within a `HandlerThread`

(I have never tried that third approach in situations like this, preferring to use one of the other alternatives, but I think that it will work)